# postfix sender_bcc_maps to local mailbox

Tags: email, postfix

I have an email relay set up using postfix. I would like to archive emails from a specific sender to a local unix mailbox on the same machine.

I have postfix configured using sender_bcc_maps, and it works when sending to another email address like so (pcre):

```
/to_be_archived@domain.com/ bcc_archiver@domain.com
```

However, I want to archive these emails to a local unix mailbox on the same system postfix is running on. I've tried using just the username, username@localhost, and several other things but so far nothing has worked, I've just gotten bounced errors in maillog.

Comment: post the maillog entry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix will deliver mail through local transport (i.e. local mailbox) if the domain destination listed in `mydestination`, see the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html). To check what is the value of `mydestination`, run command:

```
postconf mydestination
```

If there are variable string like `$myhostname` or `$mydomain`, replace it with appropiate value in `main.cf`.